# Rename shadow jar produced by shadow plugin to original artifact name

Tags: java, gradle, shadow

I am using gradle shadow plugin to build my uber jar.

build.grade file looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'


dependencies {
   compile "com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:1.3.0"

}

assemble.dependsOn(shadowJar)
```

It produces following jars in build/libs folder.

```
myProject-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
myProject-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar '//uber jar
```

I want to replace original jar with uber jar. How do i do this?

Answer (score 12):

It isn't clear why want to do this, but I'm assuming you mean "with the original JAR's name". You should do 2 things:

1. Give a different classifer to the `jar` task (or `archiveName`, or the other properties that affect the name) or disable it so that you don't constantly overwrite it on every build and avoid doing unnecessary work
2. Change the classifier on the `shadowJar` task

The [`ShadowJar`](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/blob/036f89b6d7af9f60ab8c4fdff700c6b2353eaebd/src/main/groovy/com/github/jengelman/gradle/plugins/shadow/tasks/ShadowJar.java#L28) extends from the Gradle built-in [`Jar`](https://docs.gradle.org/4.4.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Jar.html) task, so most of the configuration options from that apply to the `ShadowJar` task.

```groovy
tasks.jar.configure {
  classifier = 'default'
}

tasks.shadowJar.configure {
  classifier = null
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For least keystrokes, without burning any bridges,

replace the line:

```
assemble.dependsOn(shadowJar)
```

with:

```
jar {
    enabled = false
    dependsOn(shadowJar { classifier = null })
}
```

Verify:

> ```
> $ gradle assemble --console=plain
> :compileJava
> :processResources NO-SOURCE
> :classes
> :shadowJar
> :jar SKIPPED
> :assemble UP-TO-DATE
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps disabling the jar task in `build.gradle` will work

```
apply plugin: 'java'
jar.enabled = false
```

So you will only have your uber jar.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in that way :

```
// save the old jar task
def oldJarTask = tasks.jar

// remove the original jar tasks from the tasks list
tasks.remove(jar)

// create a new task named "jar" thats depends on shadowJar
// when you will run jar task it will be actually run the shadow jar
task jar(dependsOn:[shadowJar])

// create a task to run the plain old good jar task from gradle :)
task oldJar(dependsOn: oldJarTask)
```

This was tested and worked, hoped it helped you!